# Is there a better way than this to make bar plot of UNIQUE counts between categorical pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have pairs of categorical data but I don't want to double count instances where "toy" and "B" for instance are together multiple times.
I can do a pivot table with counts, but what I want is the equivalent of that with 1 or 0 depending if ANY matched that combo of 2 values or not, not the number of matches, 2, 3, 4, etc.

Here is an example input:

```
RS232,1.8,focused,C
RS233,2.8,chew,E
RS234,3.8,toy,D
RS235,4.8,poodle,C
RS236,5.8,winding,E
RS237,6.8,up,D
RS238,7.8,focused,B
RS239,9.8,chew,B
RS240,7.8,toy,B
RS241,6.8,toy,B
RS242,5.8,toy,A
RS243,4.8,focused,A
RS244,9.8,chew,A
RS245,8.8,chew,A
RS246,7.8,chew,C
RS247,6.8,winding,C
RS248,5.8,winding,C
RS249,4.8,winding,D
RS250,3.8,toy,D
```

The number field doesn't matter other than an earlier filtering step.  But I only want to count RS244 and RS245 as a single count in the bar plot, as making that combo twice just means people tried it a lot, not that multiple occurrences has any special meaning.

I eventually got to this data which I plotted:

```
    attrib2 group  count
0      chew     A      2
1      chew     B      1
2      chew     C      1
3      chew     E      1
4   focused     A      1
5   focused     B      1
6   focused     C      1
7    poodle     C      1
8       toy     A      1
9       toy     B      2
10      toy     D      2
11       up     D      1
12  winding     C      2
13  winding     D      1
14  winding     E      1
```

note duplicate pairs have a count > 1, but for plotting I use .value_counts so I ignore the count field and just plot how many UNIQUE items each element of attrib2 was paired with.  The Histogram I want is simply the count of the number of times each element is listed in the attrib2 column above.

[image]

The crude way I did it is this - surely there must be a cleaner, more pythonic way to accomplish this?

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import interactive

df= pd.read_csv('out.txt',sep=',',engine='c',lineterminator='\n',header='infer')

# # I am getting group/attrib2 pairs, but I want my plot to be against attrib2

groupout3 = df.groupby(['attrib2']).group.value_counts().sort_index()

# # groupby gives multiple counts for same combination, so set to 1 or leave as 0
# # following line not needed since I use value_counts below so it counts 1 if there is something there, regardless of the value, so 1, 2, etc. all get counted as 1 and 0 is 0 
# #groupout3[groupout3 != 0 ] = 1

# #convert back to DataFrame for plotting 
dfgroup = groupout3.to_frame('count')

# #make index back to column name
dfgroup.reset_index(level=['group','attrib2'], inplace=True)

# #plot categorical data counting 

plt.figure(); dfgroup.attrib2.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')

plt.show()
```

surely there is a more elegant way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a desired DF that should be plotted ? And could you also specify the column names?

Comment: could you update your question with the desired output - it's hardly possible to understand it in the comment?

Comment: The desired data frame is 2 columns, group and attrib2 with all values in each, in my case I have a count column which reflects the number of times each pair happened - I ignore that.

Comment: @MaxU hadn't seen where to edit the original post - got it now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
(df.groupby(['attrib2','group'])
   .size()
   .reset_index()
   .groupby('attrib2')
   .size()
   .plot.bar(rot=0)
)
```

[image]

data:

```
In [85]: df
Out[85]:
   attrib  num  attrib2 group
0   RS232  1.8  focused     C
1   RS233  2.8     chew     E
2   RS234  3.8      toy     D
3   RS235  4.8   poodle     C
4   RS236  5.8  winding     E
5   RS237  6.8       up     D
6   RS238  7.8  focused     B
7   RS239  9.8     chew     B
8   RS240  7.8      toy     B
9   RS241  6.8      toy     B
10  RS242  5.8      toy     A
11  RS243  4.8  focused     A
12  RS244  9.8     chew     A
13  RS245  8.8     chew     A
14  RS246  7.8     chew     C
15  RS247  6.8  winding     C
16  RS248  5.8  winding     C
17  RS249  4.8  winding     D
18  RS250  3.8      toy     D
```

Comment: nice!  Thanks - I'm pretty new to python, but knew my way was clearly a kludge :)

Comment: new to python - what is that notation with all of the dots?  I want to also be able to set colors according to resulting attrib2 column - can I do other operations inside of that structure?  I need to compare value of attrib2 with a list of special values (like (up, chew) would be red, and rest blue).  I know I can create an array of colors.